# Add custom toolbox extension to VS2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, toolbox

I would like to create an Visualstudio 2012 extension which can be used into a toolbox.
To did the following:
 - I downmloaded VS2012 sk, 
 - I did two test with VSIXProject template
and "WPF Toolbox  Controls" I guest the lastone is the most appropriated.
 - I made the classic HELLO WORD project, 
 - I built and found my VSIX, I installed it
and found that  in menu TOOLS AND UPDATES, 
 - I saw my extension installed. Then everything  worked good.

Now I expect to see my extension TOOLBOX in menu WINDOW ->> OTHER
   WINDOWS but is not there..

How can add my extension as any other  toolbox extensions?

thanks

michele

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution,
my mistake  was to use wrong  project model,
to see a own extension on VS it needs to create a "VISUAL STUDIO PACKAGE"